# How I can use "case" conditional in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I need use "case" but I don't understand how use it.
I have to do a program that read one number of month, and this program give how many days has this month.
But when I enter any number say me that the object xxx in not applicable.
Someone can help me?

```
(clear)
(display "Ingrese Un numero de Mes: ")
(define mes (read))
(if (and (integer? mes)(>= mes 1)(<= mes 12))
  (case (mes)
             ((4 6 9 11)(display 30))
             ((1 3 5 7 8 10 12) (display 31))
             (else (display 28 ))      
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had too many parentheses. It should be `(case mes ...)`, not `(case (mes) ...)`. It's not like a C-style `switch`. :-)